# Show different image on each hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have logo in different colors. I want to make that on each hover images change. Default image is black, then hover1 image is red, hover2 image is yellow, hover3 image is blue. And then again starting from black and so on. Any ideas?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried writing yourself?

Comment: Add a counter inside your hover function and play with it using modulo

Comment: you need to share the html, and image paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FKAcs/

```
var logos = ["http://placekitten.com/100", "http://placekitten.com/200", "http://placekitten.com/300"];

var i = 0;

$('#logo').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', logos[++i % logos.length]);
});
```

Essentially this maintains a counter (`i`) which increases on every `mouseover` event.

Based on the value of this counter we show the corresponding item in our `logo` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/ZLqtD/)**

```
var images=['https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a5b9d17248e0a9b953c0d5b94a9f2cb?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7512241adf8b7fb3e19c19c06f775ee3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/de2ea38f6a28646832eafb034951a982?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG'];

var counter=0;
$('#box').mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).attr('src',images[counter]);
 counter++;
 if(counter==images.length) counter = 0 ;
})
```

Comment: Why `new Array()` instead of `[]`?

Comment: i came from java :D , both are corrects

Comment: Yes, but `[]` (literal) is faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Comment: thanks for this information , i will edit :)