# Array resets after push

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that when I press the submit button it adds a value to the array but instead it keeps returning the same value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof arr == "undefined"){
        var arr = new Array();
    }

    arr.push(2);
    $("#submit").click(function(){
       console.log(arr);
    });
});
```

I want it to add a 2 each time I press submit like this:
First press

```
[2]
```

Second press

```
[2, 2]
```

But now the array just stays 2 as if it just refreshes.

Comment: If you want something to happen when you click the button, isn't it obvious that it has to be in the `click()` function?

Comment: Oh right sorry that's so stupid..

Comment: As a side note, it's recommended to use `var arr = []` instead of `new Array` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `push` is inside DOMReady. It is only ever called once. Did you mean to call it inside the `#submit` click listener?

Or does the `#submit` click actually submit a form so that you end up reloading the page, and you expect DOMReady to append to the existing array? In that case, no, it doesn't work that way, javascript variables aren't persistent across page refreshes (unless you store them in something like a cookie or localStorage)

Answer (score 3):

You should call `push()` inside your `click()` event to make it run on every click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof arr == "undefined"){
        var arr = new Array();
    }

    $("#submit").click(function(){
       arr.push(2);
       console.log(arr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the page does not know of any previous values, when you click the button you need to submit it to a server/save in storage (cookie/localStorage/etc), and on page load you should retrieve those values again, that way the array will persist across page reloads

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    arr.push(2);
    console.log(arr);
        $.each(arr, function(index, newArr){
           // console.log(newArr);
        });
    });
```