# array issue with duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my function which is part of an object and it accepts search terms as arg from a search field which is converted to string using `toString()` method. The search can consist of comma separated keywords e.g. "cloud, data, security"

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var searchVal = [$("#cc-search--field").val().trim().toLowerCase()];
    $("#cc-search--field").val('');
    // vo.sTerms.push(searchVal.toString());
    vo.addspinner();
    vo.f_constructURL(searchVal.toString());
});
f_constructURL: function (searchterms) {
    var self = this,
        rank = self.f_rank,
        url = self.f_url;
    if (self.filter_searchterms.length == 0) {
        self.filter_searchterms.push(searchterms.split(","));
    } else if (self.filter_searchterms.length > 0) {
        // reset the array
        self.filter_searchterms = [];
        self.filter_searchterms.push(searchterms.split(","));
    };
    $.grep(self.filter_searchterms, function (e, i) {
        if (self.f_searchterms.length == 0) {
            if ($.inArray(e, self.f_searchterms) === -1) self.f_searchterms.push(e);
        } else if (self.f_searchterms.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(e, self.f_searchterms) === -1) self.f_searchterms.push(e);
        }
    });
}
```

this works fine in the first run, but when I search for the same term again paired with a different keyword e.g "security, javascript" the result `f_searchterms` has

```
[
    [ "cloud", "data", "security" ], 
    [ "security", " javascript" ]
]
```

On the consequent runs I want to eliminate duplicate keywords and only add unique keywords to the `f_searchterms` and the result should look like a single array with `#n` elements.

```
[
    [ "cloud", "data", "security", "javascript" ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code since I think some tests are useless. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLybu/) for the complete code.

I first changed this :

```
if (self.filter_searchterms.length == 0){
    self.filter_searchterms.push(searchterms.split(","));
} else if(self.filter_searchterms.length > 0) {
    // reset the array
    self.filter_searchterms = [];
    self.filter_searchterms.push(searchterms.split(","));
}
```

to this :

```
self.filter_searchterms = new Array();
var myElements = searchterms.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    self.filter_searchterms.push(myElements[i]); //pushing each elements inside the list   
}
```

You wanted to always refill a new array, so I simplified the code removing tests. Then, instead of pushing an array into `filter_searchterms`, I pushed each elements of the result of the splitting.

Then I changed this :

```
if (self.f_searchterms.length == 0) {
         if ($.inArray(e, self.f_searchterms) === -1) self.f_searchterms.push(e);    
     } else if (self.f_searchterms.length > 0){
         if ($.inArray(e, self.f_searchterms) === -1) self.f_searchterms.push(e);
     }   
}
```

to this :

```
if ($.inArray(e, self.f_searchterms) === -1)
    self.f_searchterms.push(e);
```

because you were doing exactly the same bunch of code into each `if` statement, so again these tests are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nathan but I wanted to ask you a question.

Comment: @Vish I am listening to you :)

Comment: about the declaration of the array self.filter_searchterms = new Array(); As compared to self.filter_searchterms = []; is there are difference between the implicit array and the array constructor?

Comment: @Vish No. I don't think so. It is just coding style

Comment: @Vish You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array). This can lead to optimization.