# error with pushing a new item into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
imgFileName = new Array();
imgFileName = imgFileName.push(escape(theFile.name));
```

assume the theFile.name change every time a function executed.

I console log imgFilename and it return 1?

what I want is storing values into an array by push.

Comment: you should use imgFileName = [], rather than new Array() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Comment: @Lee Gary you're talking about minute optimizations.

Comment: it's just some good practices from the beginning IMO, it's generally accepted to create an array like this []

Answer (score 2):

The array [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the length of the array after the element is added to the array, so you are changing the `imgFileName` variable to hold the length of the array.

You could do:

```
var imgFileNames = [];
imgFileNames.push(escape(theFile.name));
```

And if you need to work with the file name:

```
var imgFileNames = [];
var fileName = escape(theFile.name);
imgFileNames.push(fileName);
```

Just to be clear though, you are not going to want to create the array every time right before you push a file name onto it. You will want to create it once.

Comment: how to retrieve the value within?

Comment: this would be same as op but structure is changed only.

Comment: either by index or key, something like this: imgFileNames[0]

Comment: @C-link - I don't follow. The OP was re-assigning the `imgFileName` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning the imgFileName when you assign it the operator `=`;

```
imgFileName = new Array();
imgFileName.push(escape(theFile.name));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBbW4/)

Answer (score 0):

you just push the value no need to assign it , push method returns the new length of the array

if you try to do like imgFileName=imgFileName.push(escape("name"));

imgFileName will always returns the length

```
imgFileName = new Array();
imgFileName.push(escape(theFile.name));
console.log(imgFileName);
```