# PHP Array to separate js array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 php Files. [Insert.php & Output.php]

Insert.php:
Catch 2 Dates and send it to the Output.php

Output.php:
The 2 Dates go to an mysql Query. The result i'll save to an array.

```
while($myArray = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {}
```

Now i want use this Array (myArray) in an separate js file to color the results.

```
 while($myArray = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) { 
  echo $myArray["res1"];
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
  var stats = new Array(";
  echo '"' . implode('","', $myArray) . '");';
  echo "\n</script>";}
```

in the js file i have:

```
for (var x = 0; x < stats.length; x++) {

    $(".class#" + stats[x]).css("background-color", "#e74c3c");
    $(".class2#" + stats[x]).css("background-color", "#e74c3c");
    alert(stats);
}
```

In my SQL Table i have insert 3 cols. [a1, a2 and a3]. He should color me this 3 ids [a1, a2, a3].
But he only take the first and alert me 2 times:

a1,a1

What i made wrong?

Comment: You should include your query and provide some sample data from your table.

Comment: Looks like you're going to be defining `var stats = new Array()` an awful lot of times...

Comment: This may also interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use proper way.

```
//php function
function test(){
     ...
     $array = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult);
     ...
     //after fetching your array
     echo json_encode($array)
}

<script>
    //retrieve from js
    var jsArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo test(); ?>);
    //Or
    var jsArray = jQuery.parseJSON(<?php echo test(); ?>);

</script>
```

Comment: Echo show now = {"0":"a1","col":"a1"}{"0":"a2","col":"a2"}. But my js does not color it

Comment: can i use the JSON.parse() without an function name?

Comment: ofcourse you can. rather than function put your array there

Answer (score 0):

this may work (with some modification):

```
$a = array();
while($myArray = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) { 
  array_push($a, $myArray);
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
var stats =" . json_encode($a) . ';';
echo "\n</script>";
```