# Why is the array literal syntax slower than the array constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, literals

In JavaScript, we know one language rule is that `Prefer array and object literals over their constructor`.

However, I test it in Chrome, it seems that array literal is slower than array constructor, why?

```
console.time('testconstructor'); 
var li = new Array(1, 2, 3); 
console.timeEnd('testconstructor');

console.time('testliteral'); 
var li = [1, 2, 3]; 
console.timeEnd('testliteral');
```

The results are

```
testconstructor: 0.18ms
testliteral: 0.28ms
```

Comment: What browser did you test with?  In Chrome and IE 11, the array literal is consistently faster when testing in jsfiddle.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Comment: your timing labels are reversed.  Is it possible your results are as well?

Comment: Sorry for typo, and fix it.