# Why do we need the "new" keyword when creating an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Maybe I'm asking this incorrectly, but I'm primarily wondering what is the difference between creating an array with and without the "new" keyword? When is it appropriate to use?

```
var myPix = new Array("Images/pic1.jpg", "Images/pic2.jpg", "Images/pic3.jpg");
```

I know that the the "new" keyword creates a new object. But, since I'm creating a variable that holds the array object, isn't the array still created without using "new"?

Lastly, couldn't I just as easily use this?

```
var myPix = ["Images/pic1.jpg", "Images/pic2.jpg", "Images/pic3.jpg"];
```

Comment: "*Lastly, couldn't I just as easily use this?*" - yes, and you should.

Comment: Yes, in fact I advise people who ask for my advice to (almost) forget there's such a thing as the Array constructor. Using `[ ]` notation is less typing.

Comment: _"Lastly, couldn't I just as easily use this?"_ Yup

Comment: Creating a 'new Array()' is just the classc form of doing it in coding

Comment: new is optional on native primitive constructors (String, Number, Object, RegExp, etc). except Date(), that thing is weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, "classes" are really their own constructor/initializer functions.  The `Array` function is an example.  When you call `new Array`, Javascript first creates an uninitialized object, and then invokes `Array()` with that new object as `this`.  If you run `Array()` without the `new`, you're skipping to that second step without creating any object to initialize.

With its built-in type functions like `Array`, Javascript will turn around and create the object for you even when called without `new`; they "do the right thing" because they're written that way.  Your own type functions won't be so considerate unless you go out of your way to code them so.

In general, if you're looking for shorthand notation, you should just use the bracket form.

Comment: More specifically, they "do the right thing" because the standard specifically says so for Array.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need the `new` keyword for `Array()` because is has "exotic" behavior mandated by the [ECMAScript standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-constructor):

> The Array constructor:
>
> ...
>
> - creates and initializes a new Array when called as a constructor.
> - also creates and initializes a new Array when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either way.

In JavaScript, everything is an object including arrays and a typical way to instantiate is to use the keyword new. But, for a few cases including array, this can be avoided by declaring an array like this:

```
var arr = [3,45,43,4];
```

however, the second way (using `[]`) of creating an array is preferred because:

1. it is simpler
2. it is faster

See discussion here - [Why is arr = [] faster than arr = new Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array)

Comment: Shouldnt it be `var arr = [3,45,43,4];`

Answer (score -2):

using new Array("a", "b", "c") is equivalent to ["a", "b", "c"].  The latter is called Javascript Object Notation and is more script-like ala languages such as python.  The returned object is still an Array in either case.

Comment: That's an array literal; it is __not__ JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).