# new Array() vs Array() JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Usage of the `var myArray = Array(10).fill(0);` and `var myArray = new Array(10).fill(0);` seemingly return the same result.

Are there any differences between these two expressions? When should you use the `new` keyword and when should you not?

Comment: It's in the spec that the Array constructor must work that way. Not all constructors do however.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496609/why-do-we-need-the-new-keyword-when-creating-an-array

Comment: This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205691/array-vs-new-array

Comment: Thank you @Bhojendra Rauniyar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really love your comments whenever I see you delete the post.