# Store DOM elements in array : strange behaviour?

Tags: javascript, dom

need some help over here.

I create and than, store DOM elements in a array.

Later, when i want to use them, they are like unusable, except for the last one.

Here is a realy simple code to illustrate :
http://jsfiddle.net/rd2nzk4L/

```
    var list = new Array();

    // first loop create and store elements
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        var html = '<div id="test-' + i + '" style="float: left; border: 2px solid black; width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 5px;">' + i + '</div>';

        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += html;

        var element = document.getElementById('test-' + i);

        //console.log(element);

        list.push(element);

}

// second loop use stored elements
for (index in list) {

    //console.log(list[ index ]);

    list[ index ].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

}
```

You can see only the last element became yellow.

I'll really appreciate if someone have an idea.

Thanks!

Comment: dont use for...in  with arrays as it will iterate over other properties of the array object, unless you do extra checking with hasOwnProperty etc

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `innerHTML` of the container will recreate its entire DOM tree.

Therefore, all of the old elements from the previous iteration are no longer attached to the DOM.

You should only set `innerHTML` once.

Answer (score 0):

because you aren't creating the elements, so they can't be found with the selector you are using. Try using document.createElement, then div.appendChild(element)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you set the `innerHTML` of the container, it destroys all of the child elements and recreates them. This is a problem because now your array contains references to elements that no longer exist, apart from the final iteration.

The solution is to work with DOM elements, not raw HTML.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wzxv8h5/)**

```
var list = [];

var container = document.getElementById("test");

// first loop create and store elements
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.id = 'test-' + i;
    element.className = 'mydiv';
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));

    container.appendChild(element);

    list.push(element);
}

// second loop use stored elements
for (var x=0; x<list.length; x++) {
    list[ x ].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

Side notes:

- for..in can be used on arrays, but you need to use `hasOwnProperty`, or just use a basic for loop like above.
- `var list = \[\]` is preferred to `var list = new Array()` – [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array).
- Remember to declare count variables like `i` using `var` to make them locally scoped, otherwise they will be scoped globally.