# How to find column max or min of a multidimensional javascript array using D3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to use `d3.max` or `d3.min` to find the maximum or minimum of a specific column in a multidimensional javascript array?

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    arr.push([i,Math.random()]);
}
```

From this code I'd like to do something like `d3.max(arr[*][1])` (with a wildcard, or otherwise) to get the maximum value of the second column, but specifying an index seems to require designating a row first, and then a column, which seems to limit the `d3.max` routine to row operations only.

I know I can code a separate function to extract this information, but am wondering if there is something built into the D3 API or in Javascript that will do this.

Comment: May I ask why you use new Array() instead of var arr = [];

Comment: They're effectively the same, i use both, but overall just like the way it looks.

Comment: They are the same, but arr = [] is the more efficient. "VM needs to use extra CPU cycles to figure out what new Array actually does" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375418/1837472

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remember that when I make programs that tax the CPU, but for now things are far simpler.

Comment: everything will 'tax the CPU', your task is reduce the overhead from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this using the map method:

```
arr.map(function(x){return x[1];})
```

This will return an array of the items at index "1" in each mapped element. With this, applying the `d3.max` function works fine. I guess its the solution for now.