# javascript difference between var myArray = new Array( ... ) and var myArray = ["one","two", 3]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello i a m learning the javascript and I am wondering whether you can help me understand why there are two ways to make a new array?

From book I see the author is using:

```
var myArray = new Array("one","two",3);
```

Also seeing on the web

```
var myArray = ["one","two",3];
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference?

Comment: From my understanding, they are the exact same, just a preference on which one you like better.

Comment: With array literals, the VM knows we want an array; with new Array, the VM needs to use extra CPU cycles to figure out what new Array actually does. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375418/1837472