# How to cast object to it's derived interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to cast an object (the Item interface) to it's derived interface (FileItem or FolderItem)

```
interface Item {
id: number;
name: string;
}

interface FileItem extends Item {
 size: number;
}

interface FolderItem extends Item {
  parent_id: number;
}

const files: FileItem[] = [ {id: 1, name: 'file name 1', size: 1024 } ];
const folders: FolderItem[] = [ {id:1, name: 'folder 1', parent_id: 0} ];
const items = new Array<Item>(...files, ...folders);
items.forEach(i => {
  const isFile = i as FileItem;
  if (isFile) {
   writeLog('its a file');
 }
 else writeLog('its a folder');
})
```

in the foreach loop, typescript cast all items to a FileItem which is wrong, because it should cast to FileItem and FolderItem, take a look at the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nbhhs6)

is this the way typecasting in typescript works? how to cast to the proper interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how typecasting in Typescript works. During compilation, all types are stripped so your code will end up something like this:

```js
const files = [ {id: 1, name: 'file name 1', size: 1024 } ];
const folders = [ {id:1, name: 'folder 1', parent_id: 0} ];
const items = new Array(...files, ...folders);
items.forEach(i => {
  const isFile = i;
  if (isFile) {
   writeLog('its a file');
 }
 else writeLog('its a folder');
})
```

`isFile` will always be truthy as `i` is truthy.

To get what you're after, you'll need to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). For example:

```
function isFile(item: Item): item is FileItem {
  return (item as FileItem).size !== undefined;
}
```

This checks if an `Item` has the property `size`. If it does, it must be a `FileItem`. You would use it like this:

```
items.forEach(i => {
  if (isFile(i)) {
    writeLog('its a file');
  }
  else writeLog('its a folder');
})
```

Full code:

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface FileItem extends Item {
  size: number;
}

interface FolderItem extends Item {
  parent_id: number;
}

function isFile(item: Item): item is FileItem {
  return (item as FileItem).size !== undefined;
}

const files: FileItem[] = [ {id: 1, name: 'file name 1', size: 1024 } ];
const folders: FolderItem[] = [ {id:1, name: 'folder 1', parent_id: 0} ];
const items = new Array<Item>(...files, ...folders);
items.forEach(i => {
  if (isFile(i)) {
   writeLog('its a file');
 }
 else writeLog('its a folder');
})
```

---

Also, why did you use `new Array`? You could have done this:

```
const items: Item[] = [...files, ...folders]
```

Comment: Thank you, may i ask what is the problem of using new Array instead of [...]?

Comment: @ArhHokagi [It's faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7375120/8289918) and (in my opinion) is clearer. It also helps to avoid bugs because if you invoke `new Array` with a single number (such as `new Array(2)`), it would just create an empty array with `length` 2.